# Cannot find element by name

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

the code:
[image: the code]

I want to change the value of this textbox, but I can't do it.
Here is my code for it:

`driver.find_element_by_name("inps_19_1").send_keys("value", "my value")`, not working,

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='inps_19_1']").send_keys("whatever")` not working.

Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the full HTML, but a problem I've run into a number of times was either elements being contained iframes or shadowroots that you'd have to switch to before the driver can find it. iframes are easy enough to switch to

```
driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")
```

Then you can find the element after.

If the element is contained within a shadowroot, this answer shows how to expand them https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253205/10007528