# Cannot locate element by Xpath for chrome download page

Tags: selenium

I am trying to write code to check download is completed by selenium and chrome driver. My idea is

1.Go to download page("chrome://downloads/")

2.Check the url to ensure we have downloaded file from that site (locate http://xxxxxxxx)

3.Check download status( If I found "show in folder", it implies download success. if not, download failed)

I am stucking in step2, when I try to locate the url. I used developer tools, move cursor to the url to locate the element,and then I right click and copy the xpath. The xpath is  like this

```
          //*[@id="file-link"]
```

And then I try to click ctrl+F in developer tool and paste the xpath again. I cannot locate the element. Why? Checked there is no frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Shadow DOM tree with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920167/accessing-shadow-dom-tree-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

It shadow DOM and need to select `/deep/` using CSS selector

```
downloads-manager/deep/downloads-item/deep/a[id="file-link"]
```

Comment: Thanks @ewwink, for learning purpose, can we locate it by Xpath?

Comment: AFAIK cannot using Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this could be writing a small Java utility for the same using File Class.
Something like this:

```
 File f = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\Users_" + fielName+ ".xls");
    Assert.assertTrue(f.exists());
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a better solution for my task!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Python:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# disable file preview
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option(
    'prefs', {
        'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
        'download.default_directory': '/some/download/dir',
        'download.prompt_for_download': False,
        'download.directory_upgrade': True,
        'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': True,
        'plugins.plugins_disabled': 'Chrome PDF Viewer',
        'disable-popup-blocking': True
    }
)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# start load file
driver.get('url-to-file')


def condition_load_file(dr: webdriver.Chrome):
    return dr.execute_script("""
    try {
        var el = document.querySelector("body > downloads-manager").shadowRoot.querySelector("#frb0").shadowRoot.querySelector("#show");
        return el !== null;
    } catch(exc) {
        return false;
    }
    """)


# open new window and go to chrome://downloads/
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get('chrome://downloads/')

# waiting for download to finish
WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(condition_load_file)
```