# Why Selenium is not loading svg to source_code?

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xlink

I am trying to get a website's (habr.com) `page_source` using `python3` and `selenium`, but there are some `svg` tags that contain `use` tags with `xlink:href` parameter and `#shadow-root (closed)` in them. That peace of `html` looks like this:

[image: html_source]

My `python` code is this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://habr.com/en')
source = driver.page_source
```

I am doing this using just `python` interpreter, not from file, so there is enough time to load all the resources.
So, the `source` variable will contain all the html except this `#shadow-root (closed)` part.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253205/6916032) solution, but I guess it works only with `#shadow-root (open)`.

What should I do in order to obtain the whole html source including those `Shadow DOM` parts?

**UPDATE:**
The whole point of this is that I want to make a some kind of proxy server that will point to desired website and change all the links on the page to my `localhost`. In order to make proper tests I wanted to get the source html from target website and compare it tag by tag with my `localhost`'s source html. But I cannot do that until I get this `Shadow DOM` content. I mean I can do that but it just will not be an objective test.

Comment: go to the think the xlink:href in the use tag points to and load that. Shadow roots (closed) are not directly accessible.

Comment: @RobertLongson This raises several questions. How can I know that a certain element has this `shadow DOM` in it? How do I load it and then how do I properly add the result to the `html`? If I paste the link from `xlink:href` in browser, it shows an empty page.

Comment: <use> elements have shadow DOM, other svg elements don't. You don't add the result to the html file, it's already there but inaccessible to selenium. I don't know what you're pasting or where you're putting it. I don't know why you want to do this or what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @RobertLongson I updated the question explaining the point.

Comment: grab what the use points to, put that somewhere and then change the use xlink:href to point to the local location of that content.