# Unable to find element by id on chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python and selenium automation to toggle a switch on chrome://extensions/ . On the top of the website, there is an toggle for developer mode, and I am trying to use

```
driver.find_element_by_id("knob").click()
```

however, this doesnt find the element named ID. Does anyone know how I might select the element to toggle Developer mode?

Comment: Is `chrome://extensions/` a plain html page?

Comment: @JohnGordon What do you mean By plain? It uses tags Ive never seen before, But I dont know any HTML. Could I use find by XPath?

Comment: Are you sure the button's id is named knob? I am seeing the id as `devMode` on my end.

Comment: @snnguyen I tried devMode, bar, and Knob, It cant find any Ids on that page

Comment: hmm I am unable to query any element on `chrome://extensions/`. If you're trying to test an extension, it's easier to enable it via ChromeOptions

Comment: Please add the HTML of the page for the element you want.

Comment: @snnguyen I would, But I am trying to attach 100s of extensions, but chrome options only can add 20 at a time, a limit you cant get past. I have to add them 1 by 1, so i am trying to do it this way

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, Add it as an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That element is inside ShadowDOM so you need to explicitly access it,
see [Accessing Shadow DOM tree with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37253205).

A simpler solution seems to be to call the internal API directly:

```
driver.execute_script('''
  document.querySelector("extensions-manager")
    .delegate.setProfileInDevMode(true)
''')
```