# Accessing Shadow DOM tree with Selenium using Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, shadow

Is it possible to access nested Shadow DOM objects using selenium with Firefox. In my code I am using

```
WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot",element);
    return ele;
```

It works fine with Chrome and I can access and work with Nested Shadow DOM objects. The same code fails for FireFox (89 and one before that).
Does anyone has any solution for that.
I read something here [Accessing Shadow DOM tree with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920167/accessing-shadow-dom-tree-with-selenium#) but it only works for Chrome and not Firefox.